# CS50 PSET7 Quote: 'NoneType' Error

Tags: python, cs50

I have been having some trouble with `/quote` in PSET 7 of CS50.  Every time I go into the CS50 finance site, it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

I am not sure what it means, nor how to fix it.  It seems to be automatically going to 'None' in the lookup function, but I am not sure why.  If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it!

This is my quote part of application.py:

```
@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    """Get stock quote."""
    if request.method == "POST":
        symbol = request.args.get("symbol")
        quote = lookup(symbol)
        return render_template("quoted.html", name=quote)
    else: 
        return render_template("quote.html")
```

This is my helpers.py, which is not supposed to be changed:

```
def lookup(symbol):
    """Look up quote for symbol."""

    # reject symbol if it starts with caret
    if symbol.startswith("^"):
        return None

    # reject symbol if it contains comma
    if "," in symbol:
        return None

    # query Yahoo for quote
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351911
    try:
        url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=snl1&s={}".format(symbol)
        webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        datareader = csv.reader(webpage.read().decode("utf-8").splitlines())
        row = next(datareader)
    except:
        return None

    # ensure stock exists
    try:
        price = float(row[2])
    except:
        return None

    # return stock's name (as a str), price (as a float), and (uppercased) symbol (as a str)
    return {
        "name": row[1],
        "price": price,
        "symbol": row[0].upper()
    }
```

Finally, this is my quote.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quote
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="{{ url_for('quote') }}" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="symbol" placeholder="symbol" type="symbol"text"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search for Quote</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In the future, please include the full stack trace, including line numbers and file names, not just the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer, I was supposed to put:

`symbol = request.form.get("symbol")` instead of:
`symbol = request.args.get("symbol")`.

Answer (score 1):

That error would occur when there's no `"symbol"` parameter in the request.

```
    symbol = request.args.get("symbol")
    quote = lookup(symbol)
```

Because it's not present, `.get(...)` will return `None`, and when you call `lookup(None)` it will try to run the following line, with `symbol` as `None`:

```
if symbol.startswith("^"):
```

Which means you're trying to do `None.startswith(...)`, explaining the error you see.

You could check for the case where `symbol` is missing/`None` and display an error message.

```
    symbol = request.args.get("symbol")
    if symbol:
        quote = lookup(symbol)
        return render_template("quoted.html", name=quote)
    else:
        return render_template("missing_symbol.html")
```

Or you could just ignore it: if there's no symbol, the request is probably invalid, and you can accept that it causes an error.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was wondering, how I would I be able to check whether or not symbol was missing/None?

Comment: @Emikko29 I'm glad it helped! If this solved your problem, you have the *option* of selecting it as the "accepted"/correct answer by clicking the ✔️ checkmark on the left.

Comment: @Emikko29 Sorry, I misunderstood the question in your comment. My mistake. If you haven't already found it: you could use `if "symbol" in request.args` to check if it's there, even if it's `None`.