# Python function not working properly in Jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a python function:-

```
def lookup(symbol):
    """Look up quote for symbol."""

    # reject symbol if it starts with caret
    if symbol.startswith("^"):
        return None

    # reject symbol if it contains comma
    if "," in symbol:
        return None

    # query Yahoo for quote
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351911
    try:
        url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=snl1&s={}".format(symbol)
        webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        datareader = csv.reader(webpage.read().decode("utf-8").splitlines())
        row = next(datareader)
    except:
        return None

    # ensure stock exists
    try:
        price = float(row[2])
    except:
        return None

    # return stock's name (as a str), price (as a float), and (uppercased) symbol (as a str)
    return {
        "name": row[1],
        "price": price,
        "symbol": row[0].upper()
    }
```

and I import it into my Jinja template with:-

```
app.jinja_env.globals.update(lookup = lookup)
```

In a normal python file, this:-

```
print(lookup("NFLX"))
```

produces output:-

```
{'price': 162.43, 'symbol': 'NFLX', 'name': 'Netflix, Inc.'}
```

but in my template, this :-

```
{% set stock = lookup[info['stock']] %}
{{stock['price']}}
```

gives an error :-

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'function object' has no attribute 'AAPL'
```

AAPL is the value of info['stock'], and is the stock name of Apple. I have run the same code in a normal python file, and it runs, I also tried to run another function which returns usd value of numbers in Jinja, and it runs(maybe because it is just returning a single value). Why is the lookup function not working in the template?

Comment: Does the following work? `{% set stock = lookup(info['stock']) %}` Note the round parentheses instead of square brackets.

Comment: Thank You so much sir! Can't believe did such a silly mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple syntax fix:

```
{% set stock = lookup( info['stock'] ) %}  # round brackets for function calls
```

else: you're trying to access the `value` for `key` "AAPL" in "lookup" as a `dict`, which is a function-object and not a dictionary