# Invalid Symbol for CS50 finance, even when I use the correct symbol

Tags: python, html, flask, cs50, stock

I am having trouble with getting a stock quote for CS50 Finance, no matter what stock symbol I put in, it returns the error of "invalid code" and I cannot for the life of my figure out why. I have included the relevant section of my application.py"

```
@app.route("/quote", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def quote():
    if request.method == "POST":

        quote=lookup(request.form.get("symbol"))

        if quote == None:
            return apology ("invalid symbol", 400)

        return render_template ("quoted.html", quote=quote)

    else:
        return render_template("quote.html")
```

as well as my quote.html (which seems to work)

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quote
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/quote" method="post">
        <div class= "form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name ="symbol" placeholder = "type symbol here" type="text" require/>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Get quote</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and my quoted.html (which I never get to see, because I am get the apology returned:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Quoted
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <p> Today, a share of {{ quote ["symbol"] }} will cost you {{ quote ["price"] | usd }}.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

EDIT: here is the lookup from helpers.py, I didn't write this code, it was provided for the CS50 class:

```
"""Look up quote for symbol."""

    # reject symbol if it starts with caret
    if symbol.startswith("^"):
        return None

    # reject symbol if it contains comma
    if "," in symbol:
        return None

    # query Yahoo for quote
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351911
    try:
        url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=snl1&s={}".format(symbol)
        webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        datareader = csv.reader(webpage.read().decode("utf-8").splitlines())
        row = next(datareader)
    except:
        return None

    # ensure stock exists
    try:
        price = float(row[2])
    except:
        return None

    # return stock's name (as a str), price (as a float), and (uppercased) symbol (as a str)
    return {
        "name": row[1],
        "price": price,
        "symbol": row[0].upper()
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your `lookup` function? Try printing `request.form.get("symbol")` to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Show your code for `lookup()`

Comment: added code for lookup() in an edit

Comment: The URL in your `lookup` function doesn't work. There's no such site as `download.finance.yahoo.com`. It may be an old exercise and the URL has changed.

Comment: The Yahoo Finance API has been shut down: https://www.quora.com/Did-Yahoo-Stock-API-shut-down

Comment: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dowload.finance.yahoo.com`. You're going to need a Plan B.

Comment: Here is the [current spec](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/tracks/web/finance/) which includes the distro code download info, for CS50x finance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I wanted to post a formal answer, but I have to give thanks to you guys in the credits. GAEfan pointed me in the right direction that the issue might be in my lookup(). Then Barmar pointed out that the website used for my lookup() was no longer in use. I don't know what happened but I downloaded the distribution code from the official CS50 link, maybe I hit a glitch or had an error in my download, but re downloading the distribution code, allowed me to get the most current version for the lookup() function. Didn't plan on answering my own question, but wanted to close this one out and give thanks to everyone for helping me.